# Copy instance of Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm currently using Python (3.6.3) Selenium to access a website and scrape data from it.
The website contains a section such as the following:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Each `<li></li>` is a link that I want to press on, then collect the data on that website.

My solution is to load the main page, 
then copy its session, clicking on one link,
then copying the session again and click on the next link.

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS("phantomjs")
browser2 = browser
```

Thats what I want to do, but when I do that, `browser2` points to `browser`, so whenever I change `browser2`, `browser` changes.

I want to make `browser2` a copy of `browser`, so that I can just reset `browser2` whenever I want.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the issue here, but I guess you wish to navigate all the links, you don't need a new instantiation of webdriver for that, without going into parallelism you could simple go to the first links, use browser.back() for instance and select a new one, etc rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are assigning browser to broswer2, browser2 is essentially a reference to browser object hence broswer2 and browser both points to the same object. What you can do to solve this issue is use a Python's standard copy module

```
import copy

browser2 = copy.copy(browser)
```

Now both object can be modified independently

From copy docs:

> Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create
>   bindings between a target and an object. For collections that are
>   mutable or contain mutable items, a copy is sometimes needed so one
>   can change one copy without changing the other. This module provides
>   generic shallow and deep copy operations

Read more about copy module [here in docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

Comment: you may want deepcopy instead to avoid conflicts. 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy

Comment: when you browser.get('https://example.com') the browser2.current_url will be also https://example.com ....